# Function calls in function decoration

Tags: python, python-decorators

When decorating a function, you can use a method `@object.method`, and you can use methods of attributes of attributes and so on `@object.attribute.attribute.method`. You may also pass extra arguments to the decorator `@function(foo="bar")`.

However, it appears that these conflict. When there is a function call in the chain, python appears to assume that it's the bit where you pass arguments to the decorator, and any chains after that are a SyntaxError.

Is there anything I'm missing here? A reason for this behaviour or a way to work around it?

This code was written for Python 3.4.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Decorator:
    def decorate(self, callback):
        return callback

_dec = Decorator()
def findit():
    return _dec

class B: dec = _dec
class A: bar = B()
foo = A()

dec = findit()
@dec.decorate
#@findit().decorate
#Above line is a syntax error
@foo.bar.dec.decorate #also permitted
def function():
    pass
```

Error:

```
  File "test.py", line 17
    @findit().decorate
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Try `@(findit().decorate)`. Could be a precedence issue?

Comment: `@(findit().decorate)` gives a syntax error on the opening bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) for decorators is something like:

```
decorator: '@' dotted_name [ '(' [arglist] ')' ] NEWLINE
decorators: decorator+
decorated: decorators (classdef | funcdef | async_funcdef)
```

Here `dotted_name` is(AKA `foo`, `foo.bar.spam` etc):

```
dotted_name: NAME ('.' NAME)*
```

From the grammar it's clear that the parenthesis can only be followed by a newline not another `dotted_name`, hence it throws a syntax error.

So, to fix this make sure the function call is always at the end, if there's a function call in-between you must assign it to a variable beforehand(taken from your code only):

```
dec = findit()
@dec.decorate
```

---

For the history related to the decorator syntax you can go through this doc: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators

Answer (score 2):

You already have the workaround within your question. Just evaluate `findit()` before applying it as a decorator:

```
dec = findit()
@dec.decorate
def function():
    pass
```

Remember that the `@decorator` syntax is just syntactic sugar, so the above is equivalent to:

```
def function():
    pass

function = findit().decorate(function)
```